# Select an area in rep graph not working on Chrome

Tags: support, reputation-graph, google-chrome

https://stackoverflow.com/users/95810/alex-martelli?tab=reputation

The "select an area by dragging across the lower chart" thing is not working on Chrome.

Tested with Chrome 13.0.782.220 m, works with Firefox 6.0.1 and IE 8

Quirk: For some reason, if I open an incognito window, it works. Tried clearing the cache and cookies, still not working.

Comment: Works just fine here, Chrome 15.0.861.0 dev on Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: Working fine on Chrome 13.0.782.220 on OSX 10.7.

Comment: Fine on Chromium 14.0.835.126 on Linux.

Comment: LOL, has anyone been able to reproduce the bug at all? I am on Windows BTW

Comment: Yes, I have the same issue `12.0.742.112 (90304) Ubuntu 11.04`.  jonsca answer below worked.

Comment: Same issue here too, it worked in chrome previously

Comment: it's not working in FireFox at least one year regardless of zoom level.

Comment: Still broken with zoom levels other than 100% in Chromium 51.0.2704.79-0ubuntu0. (Ubuntu 15.10)

Comment: It's not working for me in Chrome even at 100% zoom level. Chrome 58.0.3029.110 on Windows 10.

Comment: Site is using an old version of HighCharts. Seems to be fixed in newer versions, but the version on SO is from 2011.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Zoom out to full view (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>0</kbd> on PC keyboard, or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> on Mac keyboard) and it will work.

I'm not sure what the details are, but something doesn't register properly when you are zoomed in.

Comment: It doesn't fix it for me, and it's not working in FireFox either these days. After you click in the lower graph, the highlighted area follows the mouse pointer, but never releases even after clicking again, moving away etc. and the upper graph does not update.

Comment: @Chris I would start a new question if it's pertaining to a specific Firefox version, the versions mentioned here are ancient history, so I don't know if it's even the same bug.

Comment: Hi @jonsca - It's not, it's happening in latest versions of Chrome and Firefox - though not IE10 amazingly!! ;-) - I didn't want to 'clutter' Meta, but if you still think I should open a new question I will do?

Comment: @Chris Works fine for me in FF 20.  You are highlighting along the bottom graph and not the top one?

Comment: (even with the zoom on, it still works, seemingly)

Comment: @jonsca Yes, I am clicking on the bottom graph. FF 20.0.1 and Chrome  26.0.1410.64 on Windows 7 64-bit. I've just tried some other profiles (including yours) and same broken behaviour on all.

Comment: @jonsca Will do - many thanks. UPDATE: I found a more recent question and have upvoted that rather than duplicate. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164221/reputation-graph-in-firefox-seems-broken

Comment: Just a correction: It needs to be at 100% zoom level, and if you have set the default zoom level to be > 100%, Ctrl-0 isn't enough.

Comment: For me actually the only time it displays incorrectly is at 100%. If I zoom in then it displays correctly. If I zoom out from 100% then it displays correctly.  But if I'm at 100%... it doesn't work.