# Can't select an area by dragging across the lower chart on the new rep graph

Tags: bug, profile-page, reputation-graph

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Select an area in rep graph not working on Chrome](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105061/select-an-area-in-rep-graph-not-working-on-chrome)

[image: select an area by dragging across the lower chart]

does not work on the new [rep graph](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/146495/kevin-vermeer?tab=reputation&sort=graph).

Current Chrome (15.0.874.121), Windows XP, behind a proxy.

The Console reports one warning:

> Resource interpreted as Other but transferred with MIME type undefined.

No Resource is shown with a type of "Other"; after a hard refresh the Network tab shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3Fj8.png).  On Electrical Engineering, my [rep tab](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/857/kevin-vermeer?tab=reputation) works properly, and shows [almost identical results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnqDH.png).  It also works properly on Stack Overflow, and it works properly in Firefox and Opera.  Results are unchanged when I enable or disable extensions.

I posted this as an answer to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112151/new-user-page-live-on-meta/112304#112304 (10k only; answer was deleted because that thread was out of control), but I didn't have dev tool reports at the time.

1. Why doesn't this work for me?  It seems to be [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) for Nick Craver.
2. What else should I check?  I'm no web dev, so a little help would be appreciated.

Comment: Selecting a date range used to only work in Chrome when you zoomed to normal (ctrl+0).  I'm not sure if that's the case with the new user page.

Comment: ([the question about the "old" User page, for reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105061/select-an-area-in-rep-graph-not-working-on-chrome/105086#105086))

Comment: @jonsca - Sigh.  Yes, that's the problem, and that's why it worked on my other browsers and other OS.  I browse zoomed-in on Stack Exchange most of the time at work because I've got a 1900px wide screen that I sit well back from, and normal zoom leaves almost 1000px of white bars on each side.

Comment: I don't remember how I finally figured that out, but it was maddening before hand.