# Reputation graph selection doesn't work

Tags: bug, reputation-graph

[Reputation Graph Area Selection not Working in Chrome](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277820/260198) [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) (?!)

[Reputation graph timeline does not work in Firefox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260239/260198)

No errors in console. Selection just doesn't work.

> [image]

**Repro:**  Win7, Firefox 62.0x64

Comment: Note to potential dupe close voters: the team prefers that users file new bug reports if the same bug from earlier comes up again.

Comment: Works fine for me, Firefox Nightly 64.0a1.

Comment: Works as well, latest Safari

Comment: Are you zoomed in or out?

Comment: Frequently (not always) happens for me. I'm on Brave for Windows 10, version 0.23.107. Used to happen on Opera for windows, but I don't know what version I was using.

Comment: @muru no. But 100% reproduction =/