# Can't select reputation graph date range in Chrome

Tags: support, reputation-graph, google-chrome

Works fine in IE, but in latest Chrome the part of the graph that says "select an area by dragging across the lower chart" doesn't actually respond to mouse input.

Comment: can´t repro that with Chrome 31.0.1650.63 on Win7 x64

Comment: im on the same browser version but running Win8.1 x64

Comment: Can't repro with Chrome Version 31.0.1650.63 on Win8.1 x64

Comment: Reproed on Version 31.0.1650.63 Win 7 x64. Just came here to report it and found this. Exact same version as @SnowballChristmasLight but different results!

Comment: Using Chrome Version 31.0.1650.63 m on Windows 8.1. No zoom. Can't select the date range either. Also, hovering over the upper chart's columns does not produce a pop up and clicking a column does not produce a list of comments below the chart. Works on my other computer with Chrome on Win 7 (will provide version).

Comment: **v32.0.1700.77 on OS X** ... same issue here.

Comment: OK. I know what the issue is. It doesn't work when you aren't at the default zoom level. Duplicate of [Select an area in rep graph not working on Chrome](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105061/145673)