# Eeeek! Reputation graph numbers overflowing all over space!

Tags: bug, reputation-graph

On the Network rep graph, when I zoom in or move a account with higher reputation away the numbers go all over the rep graph.

[image]

## Remove Linguistics.SE account from graph

Eeeek!

[image]

I'm not at 151 rep on ELL before I started getting active by asking a question!

## Zoom in on graph

Eeeek!

[image]

Hey, I'm all above 100 rep on all of these days in the zoom on Linguistics SE and it was 101 rep on ELL.SE these days!

## 1 year later

It's even messier with 4 accounts:
[image]
How come the X axis just stops before Sep 2019? And how come 300 is above 600?

Comment: I'm certain this has been reported, but I can't seem to find the duplicate at the moment….

Comment: Similar: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290539/zoom-on-reputation-graph-in-network-profile-not-working-in-chrome and from long ago: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105061/select-an-area-in-rep-graph-not-working-on-chrome - I can confirm FF Android in desktop mode is broken. Zixuan, please check if those describe your complaint.

Comment: I'm on Windows 10, desktop, using Firefox.

Comment: [*Eeeek!* meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/83625#83625)