# The lines on the Reputation graph's area selector are invisible in Chrome

Tags: bug, status-completed, google-chrome, reputation-graph, visibility

This concerns the graph view on the reputation tab of your profile. (i.e. [this thing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/152515/jonathan-hobbs?tab=reputation&sort=graph&StartDate=2014-02-01%2010:42:41Z))

In Chrome, the area selector doesn't show its bars.

Something similar appear to have been reported [in 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105061/152515), but this is a completely different one. This isn't solved by returning to default zoom - in fact, the bars are somewhat visible in any zoom level *except* for the default one.

### Firefox 26:

[image: Works fine]

### Chrome 32:

[image: Part of it doesn't show up]

(Note the absence of the little spikes along the bottom row, or that specifically, they're white.)

Comment: Looks like it's a dupe actually - and that the bug's been around for a few months.