# Reputation graph doesn't show in Chrome when selecting larger timeframes

Tags: bug, google-chrome, reputation-graph

I'm able to select up to about 13 of the most recent months and still get a graph—

[image]

But go a little beyond that, and—

[image]

But the "maximum" timeframe isn't consistent. Below I've selected just short of *12* months—

[image]

And here's me extending the front of it to cover just past 12 months—

[image]

I'm on Windows 7, and the graphs work fine in other browsers (IE 10, FF 28, Safari 5.1.7), so the issue seems to be only with Chrome. I'm running the release channel,

> Version 33.0.1750.154 m

I saw [Select an area in rep graph not working on Chrome](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105061/select-an-area-in-rep-graph-not-working-on-chrome) and made sure I'm not zoomed in or out. Can anyone else reproduce this?

Comment: I would upvote, but your current rep of 1234 is just so perfect :D

Comment: Haha. I've taken a screenshot. Please, _as you were_... ;-)

Comment: Next stop, reputation = 1337!

Comment: It is not just you...I repro-ed this as well, same OS/Chrome version.

Comment: FWIW, I can't repro this on Chromium 33.0.1750.152 / Kubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Good to know @IlmariKaronen, thanks. Seems to be specific to Chrome on Windows 7. Can anyone reproduce this on Windows 8? In any case, it's probably a bug in Chrome—I've been having all sorts of issue with Chrome lately, despite many reinstallations.